# Как найти среднюю оценку по городам в SQL

Tags: sql

Стоит задача: Найти среднюю оценку каждого города, в котором есть университет. Проблема в том что у меня около 10 городов и приходиться каждый раз писать WHERE и название города например (SELECT ID FROM UNIVERSITIES  WHERE CITY='Киев'). Буду признателен за помощь если подскажите как можно это оптимизировать чтобы вручную не писать каждый город.

```
   SELECT AVG (MARK)
    FROM EXAM_MARKS E
    WHERE STUDENT_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM STUDENTS WHERE UNIV_ID IN (
               SELECT ID FROM UNIVERSITIES  WHERE CITY='Киев'))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо сделать `JOIN` через все таблицы и `GROUP BY`.
Что-то типа такого:

```
SELECT u.CITY, AVG(e.MARK) as avgMark
FROM UNIVERSITIES u
JOIN STUDENTS s ON u.ID=s.UNIV_ID
JOIN EXAM_MARKS e ON s.ID=e.STUDENT_ID
GROUP BY u.CITY
```